# Getting data from C# to Excel 03/07

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I have files with tons of real time data that I process with an C# application. After processing the data it is presented in Excel using a specific template.

This is solved using Interop today. I must say I don't completely gasp the whole Interop situation. Do I have to manually install the Interop functionality on each end user terminal somehow? How does it handle the mix of 2003/2007 versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the structure of your Excel document (and presuming you don't want and kind of complex macros/ functions/ etc within the Excel document) you can generate XML using the Excel XML format. **I'm not referring to OpenXML, I'm referring to the XML format used by Excel prior to 2007.**

I cover how to do it here: http://www.aaron-powell.com//blog/september-2008/linq-to-xml-to-excel.aspx

The problem with Interop is that it isn't really designed to hard core document generation. If you try and do a lot of document processing you can run into locks

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). You shouldn't have to do anything with the Excel installation.

Answer (score 0):

We use [SyncFusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/xlsio/backoffice/default.aspx) which works pretty well. Pretty easy to use too.

Comment: The only download is you have to pay, and the license isn't cheap

Comment: Way to expensive to even consider for my use.

Comment: The only download? Anyways, you didn't write anything about licenses or prices. You said that you have "files with tons of real time data", so I thought it maybe was talking about a bigger, commercial project =)

Comment: "bigger, commercial project" does not mean "budget".  Trust me.  I had to write these stupid Excel things for a large trading floor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are getting at, but you can read and write Excel files via ADO.NET.  This is not interop, nor is it XML file processing.   [Example](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=data&file=excel-adonet.cs).

Comment: This would be my second preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Excel 2007 format use [Office Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en), you can find samples [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508943.aspx).
I used for some developments and is a bit tricky at the beginning if you have to create the file from scratch, but if you have a template as in your case, then it is easier. It is fast and don't need to have excel installed in the server.